# Unable to search address on Google Geocoder API with business account

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api, geocode

I tried to search for an address through a Geocoder google API but I could not find it.

Address trying to look for: 29 Esplanade, St Helier JE2 3QA, Jersey, UK

Please see the formed URL as below which is not working:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29+Esplanade%2c+St+Helier+JE2+3QA%2c+Jersey%2c+UK&sensor=false&new_forward_geocoder=true&region=UK&client=client_Id&channel=channel_ID&components=country%3aUK&signature=signature

Above mentioned URL is not working with business account. I've not mentioned Clint Id, signature & Channel Id in above URL.

I also tried to search the same address without business account and it works.
Url: [https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29+esplanade+st+helier](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29%20esplanade%20st%20helier)
The above mentioned URL works fine.

Would you please provide some options? What is wrong in my approach? Please let me know if you need any more details from me to resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address "`29 Esplanade, St Helier JE2 3QA, Jersey, UK`" is not part of United Kingdom ([Jersey is not part of the United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jersey)), and as you are applying filter for `country:UK` is not displaying address.

1) Change the component query from `country:UK` to `country:JE`

2) regenerate signature and replace signature with new one.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29+Esplanade%2c+St+Helier+JE2+3QA%2c+Jersey%2c+UK&sensor=false&new_forward_geocoder=true&region=UK&client=client_Id&channel=channel_ID&components=country%3aJE&signature=signature

Note: You can also remove the `The component filters` query from url. `The component filters` will fully restrict the result from geocoder. and the `region` will not fully restrict the result. you can find it on [google here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#geocoding)

Comment: Thanks sangram parmar for your quick response and its wokring for me

Answer (score 0):

I got new solution for restriction of address for multiple countries and regions.

here we can update our component query in our geocoder url like

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29+esplanade+st+helier&sensor=false&new_forward_geocoder=true&region=UK&client=client_Id&channel=chenal_ID&components=country%3aUK%7ccountry%3aJE&signature=signature](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=29%20esplanade%20st%20helier&sensor=false&new_forward_geocoder=true&region=UK&client=client_Id&channel=chenal_ID&components=country%3AUK%7Ccountry%3AJE&signature=signature)

Hence , we can search our address in these bounded countries and regions.

Thank you.

Cheers!